# Why is dot metacharactor of regex not working in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have two records with names `bowser` and `Tommy` in the table `pet`. Now when I run the following query in cmd nothing happen:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '.%';
```

On the other hand the following query matches `Bowser` record:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE 'b%';
```

As far as I know, `.` should match any character. So '.%' should match every word.

> Why is dot metacharactor of regex not working in mysql?

Comment: @anubhava But the doc says we can http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: DOT is only to be used for `RLIKE` that uses regex

Comment: `.*`  will match any string, not word. Even an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your query doesn't work is because it is looking for names that start with a period.  That is how `LIKE` works.

Use `RLIKE` or `REGEXP`:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '.*';
```

`LIKE` uses the ANSI standard for the operator.  The equivalent of `.` is `_`.  However, the way `LIKE` works is different from regular expressions.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) does a good job of explaining the differences between `LIKE` and `REGEXP`.

Comment: I tried both `SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name REGEXP '.%';` , `SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name RLIKE '.%'; But they return `Empty set`.

Comment: I guess `%` doesn't go right with REGEXP. `WHERE name REGEXP '^b';` worked fine!.

Comment: @user31782 . . . I would expect from your question that you would know that *any* characters sequence would be `'.*'`.  The pattern `.%'` looks for a period followed by a percent sign.